# ListView click show/hide all check box

Tags: android, listview

I am having a listview and it has one checkbox and two textfields , i would like to change check box visibility properties from listview on click funtion, i am able to change the properties from inside the getView funtion but i want it from listview click. Help me find a solution

```
public class HelpList extends Fragment {

amfFunctions amf;
MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
Database_Contact contact = new Database_Contact();
DBHelper mydb = new DBHelper(getActivity());
public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
public String user_phone_number;
public String buddyName;
public String buddyNum;
LayoutInflater vi;
View v ;
Fragment fragment = null;
Button myAddButton,myDelButton;
int selected = 0;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector cd;
ArrayList<Database_Contact> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
Database_Contact addcontacts = new Database_Contact();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_helplist, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    displayListView();
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());
    myDelButton = (Button)v. findViewById(R.id.deleteContact);
    myDelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                DeleteContact();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),     
 getString(R.string.nointernet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Constants.i = 0;
    myAddButton = (Button)v. findViewById(R.id.Addanother);
    myAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            Log.e("Myaddbutton text ", (String) myAddButton.getText());
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                if (myAddButton.getText().equals("Close")){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
 getString(R.string.click_to_close), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    AddContact();
                }

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
 getString(R.string.nointernet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}

private void displayListView() {
    mydb = new DBHelper(getActivity());
    ArrayList<Database_Contact> contactlist = (ArrayList<Database_Contact>) 
mydb.getAllDatabase_Contacts();

    Collections.sort(contactlist, new Comparator<Database_Contact>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Database_Contact lhs, Database_Contact rhs) {
            return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
        }
    });

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), 
 R.layout.activity_allcontactlist, contactlist);
    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.helplistview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Database_Contact contact = (Database_Contact) 
 parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            contact.isSelected();
        }
    });
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Database_Contact> {

    private ArrayList<Database_Contact> contactlist;
    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Database_Contact> contactlist) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, contactlist);
        this.contactlist = new ArrayList<Database_Contact>();
        this.contactlist.addAll(contactlist);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        TextView Number;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_allcontactlist, 
null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.code = (TextView) 
 convertView.findViewById(R.id.helplist_name);
            holder.Number = (TextView) 
 convertView.findViewById(R.id.helplist_num);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) 
 convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_all);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
            final ViewHolder finalHolder1 = holder;

            holder.code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (finalHolder1.name.isShown() == false){
                        Constants.i = Constants.i+1;
                        myDelButton.setEnabled(true);
                        finalHolder.name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if(finalHolder1.name.isShown() == true) {
                        finalHolder.name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Constants.i = Constants.i-1;
                        if (Constants.i == 0){
                            myDelButton.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.Number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (finalHolder1.name.isShown() == false){
                        Constants.i = Constants.i+1;
                        myDelButton.setEnabled(true);
                        finalHolder.name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if(finalHolder1.name.isShown() == true) {
                        finalHolder.name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Constants.i = Constants.i-1;
                        if (Constants.i == 0){
                            myDelButton.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Database_Contact contact = (Database_Contact) 
 cb.getTag();
                    contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Database_Contact contact = contactlist.get(position);
        holder.code.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.Number.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
        holder.name.setText("");
        holder.name.setChecked(contact.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(contact);
        return convertView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find any perfect solution i tried it in a different manner alough its a bit diffenrt from what i wanted i.e on click i used my displayListView() funtion and got the work done

```
         ischeckboxVisible = true;
         Runnable run = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             displayListView();
         }
         };
         getActivity().runOnUiThread(run);
```

and coming to getView i have used:

```
            if (!ischeckboxVisible)
            {
                holder.name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (ischeckboxVisible)
            {
                holder.name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

so every time i do the click it changes the ischeckboxVisible to either true or false and initializes the displatListview() and it works.

I have had help from here [Android hide and show checkboxes in custome listview on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945528/android-hide-and-show-checkboxes-in-custome-listview-on-button-click)

Hope this might come in handy for some one out there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code if it helps you,

```
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Database_Contact contact = (Database_Contact) contactlist.get(position);
               contact.setSelected(!contact.isSelected());

              if(contact.isSelected())
              {
                  ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_all)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
              else
               {
                 ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_all)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
    }
});
```

Comment: its working for a only first row if i try to click other row its not working..........i want all my checkboxs to be visible at a single click and the above idea doesnot work that way....................thanks for the idea though

Comment: Check your requirement again what you have mentioned, you mentioned that if you click on list view item then it should set visibility of that check box not all

Comment: yaa i know your answer does work for row one but it does not work if i click on some other it stills edits the first row only

Comment: For that you need to change below line :   
 Database_Contact contact = (Database_Contact) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

by

 Database_Contact contact = (Database_Contact) contactlist.get(position);

Comment: i tried it and its still the same i am not able to get the position of the checkbox  to changes the visibility its only accepting position "0" but from above answer the value inside the contact array changes correctly. if i click on the second row its still changing the first row only

Comment: do one thing    contact.setSelected(!contact.isSelected()); 

after this line comment that if() block and just write down below code and check output
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();