# How to change the CheckBox Visiblity by clicking on listview item

Tags: android

I have a listview, in which there are one text view and checkbox. If I click on listview item the first time, the checkbox will be visible.If I click on the same list item a second time, the check box will be gone.

How to do that?

Source code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>(100);
    ListView lv_numbers;
    TextView set_TxtView;
    int count_new=1,count_changed=1;

    public static boolean firstTime=false,firstTime_changed=false;

    Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.numbers_layout);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        }
        lv_numbers=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_numbers);
        set_TxtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.set_TxtView);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0) {
                numbers.add("Neelima Maddala");
            }
            else{
                numbers.add("Neelu Neelima");
            }
        }
        Log.e("num","num"+numbers);

        final NumbersAdapter num_adapter = new NumbersAdapter(MainActivity.this,numbers);
        lv_numbers.setAdapter(num_adapter);

        lv_numbers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selectedFromList = (String) lv_numbers.getItemAtPosition(position);
                set_TxtView.setText(selectedFromList);
                int cntChoice = lv_numbers.getCount();
                Log.e("hi", "hi" + cntChoice);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class NumbersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> numbers_array = new ArrayList<>();
    ViewHolder holder;
    public static boolean firstTime_new=false;
    boolean check;


    public NumbersAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> numbers_array) {
        this.context = activity;
        this.numbers_array= numbers_array;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numbers_array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return numbers_array.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ll_base=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_base);
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_number);
            holder.checkbox= (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String numb=String.valueOf(numbers_array.get(position));
        holder.number.setText(numb);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView number;
        RelativeLayout ll_base;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }
}
```

Comment: U can bind a default boolean flag to all the row elements individually and On Item Click u can retreive the boolean flag and toggle it using if else condition and depending upon the boolean tag u can make checkbox visible and gone accordingly

Comment: Can you please explain in detail with source code.

Answer (score 2):

modify ur getView method like this :

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ll_base=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_base);
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_number);
            holder.checkbox= (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String numb=String.valueOf(numbers_array.get(position));
        holder.ll_base.setTag(false);
        holder.number.setText(numb);
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        holder.ll_base.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( ((Boolean)holder.ll_base.getTag()).booleanValue()== false){
               holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);
                holder.ll_base.setTag(true)
            }else{
          holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ll_base.setTag(false);
         }
        }
    });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Please Ignore The Typos.

Comment: This becomes shows an error as incompatable object and boolean.

Comment: incompatable object and boolean

Comment: no i am not getting the output what i want exactly is if i click on listview item checkbox will be visible.if click on same listview item checkbox will be gone.

Comment: what issue are u getting with the above solutions??

Comment: checkbox is visible at multiple positions

Comment: Then i think my answer will atleast not show u the checkbox at multiple positions until u click the item

Comment: can you please tell me what will return this line "holder.ll_base.getTag()"

Comment: Now i changed it plzz check and tell me the output

Comment: @M.Neelima please check the edit and tell me whether it is working??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144553/discussion-between-m-neelima-and-roy).

Comment: it will not perform any action Mr.Roy

Comment: did u run it and see??

Comment: yes,it is also showing checkboxes at mutliple positions

Comment: Now Add this line like i did  holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE); check my edit

Comment: @M.Neelima  output vachinda??

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for your list item click,

```
lv_numbers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String selectedFromList = (String) lv_numbers.getItemAtPosition(position);
            set_TxtView.setText(selectedFromList);
            int cntChoice = lv_numbers.getCount();
            Log.e("hi", "hi" + cntChoice);

            CheckBox selectedCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

           if(selectedCheckBox.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
           {
               selectedCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }
           else
           {
              selectedCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If i scroll down the listview checkbox is visible at multiple positions

Comment: If you scroll your listview and the selected item becomes invisible and you scroll back, then the child view will come with the default layout. It wouldn't maintain the state automatically, you have to keep it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to maintain that state

Comment: for maintaining the state u have to write the code in getView()

Comment: You can do it in two way:First you can pass a custom class which having two fields one will be your string and another boolean value that you will update on checkbox change. Second: add one more field in adapter i.e. Map and save the state with position as key and boolean value as value. In your getView you have to check the state from either.

Comment: No need to write code in getView(), instead of that you need to take one boolean variable and then need to manage it.

Comment: For more details check below answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893659/listview-click-show-hide-all-check-box/37895362#37895362

Comment: I cant understand that answer.